# Ember Module Unification Stack trace: Error: Assertion Failed: 'data-adapter' is not a recognized type

Tags: javascript, ember.js, model, ember-data, ember-cli

Ember data won't show on the inspector.The error is showing below. 
I am using module unification in new ember. [module unification ember](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0143-module-unification.md)

Can someone tell me how to fix it because I need to see data in ember inspector?

The data show an empty data which I see the model but there is nothing(image below):

```
Ember Inspector has errored.
This is likely a bug in the inspector itself.
You can report bugs at https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector.
Error message: Assertion Failed: 'data-adapter' is not a recognized type
Stack trace: Error: Assertion Failed: 'data-adapter' is not a recognized type
    at assert (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73088:19)
    at Resolver._definitiveCollection (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73063:31)
    at Resolver.identify (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73027:37)
    at Resolver.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73055:27)
    at Class.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:98399:36)
    at Class.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:98232:25)
    at Class.superWrapper [as resolve] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:41053:22)
    at _resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12906:36)
    at Registry.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12445:21)
    at Registry.resolve (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:12450:60)
warn @ VM2062:92
handleError @ VM2062:149
(anonymous) @ VM2062:3515
_run @ backburner.js:1066
run @ backburner.js:748
run @ index.js:111
wrap @ VM2062:3511
messageReceived @ VM2062:3482
get.onMessageReceived.message @ VM2062:3476
get.forEach.callback @ VM2062:127
_messageReceived @ VM2062:126
run @ VM2062:344
_run @ backburner.js:1066
run @ backburner.js:748
run @ index.js:111
chromePort.addEventListener.event @ VM2062:343
```

file tree:

```
src
├── data
│   └── models
│       ├── application
│       │   └── model.js
│       └── user
│           ├── adapter.js
│           └── model.js
├── formats.js
├── init
│   └── initializers
│       └── i18n.js
├── main.js
├── resolver.js
├── router.js
├── services
│   └── intl.ts
└── ui
    ├── components
    ├── index.html
    ├── routes
    │   ├── about-page
    │   │   ├── route.js
    │   │   └── template.hbs
    │   ├── application
    │   │   ├── controller.js
    │   │   ├── route.js
    │   │   └── template.hbs
    │   └── user
    │       ├── controller.js
    │       ├── route.js
    │       └── template.hbs
    ├── styles
    │   └── app.css
    └── utils
```

This is the file structure of the module unification. There is nothing special in the package.json.

After adding those configuration (from [@NullVoxPopuli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356849/nullvoxpopuli)) to the resolver.js

```
  "data-adapter": { definitiveCollection: "main" },
  "container-debug-adapter": { definitiveCollection: "main" },
  "resolver-for-debugging": { definitiveCollection: "main" }

  assign(moduleConfig.collections, {
    data: { types: ["data-adapter", "model"], defaultType: "model" }
});
```

[image: PIC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is def one of the rougher parts of module unification at the moment.

So far, I've been able to get the data tab on the inspector to be loaded with this resolver config:

```
import Resolver from 'ember-resolver/resolvers/fallback';

import buildResolverConfig from 'ember-resolver/ember-config';
import config from '../config/environment';

let moduleConfig = buildResolverConfig(config.modulePrefix);

moduleConfig.types = Object.assign(moduleConfig.types, {
  // ember-inspector support
  'data-adapter': { definitiveCollection: 'main' },
  'container-debug-adapter': { definitiveCollection: 'main' },
  'resolver-for-debugging': { definitiveCollection: 'main' },
});

moduleConfig.collections.main.types.push('data');

moduleConfig.collections = Object.assign(moduleConfig.collections, {
  data: {
    types: ['data-adapter', 'model'],
    defaultType: 'model',
  },
});

export default Resolver.extend({
  config: moduleConfig,
});
```

with this config, the models are only picked up if they are named in `src/data/models/{model-name}.js` -- if a model is at `src/data/models/{model-name}/model.js`, this does not tell the inspector where to look.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. 
I noticed that if I remove this part 
```
moduleConfig.collections = Object.assign(moduleConfig.collections, {
  data: {
    types: ['data-adapter', 'model'],
    defaultType: 'model',
  },
});
```
The inspector still works as well. Do I really need this part?

Comment: my app needed it, but I don't know 100% for sure if every app will need it. my app is a couple weeks behind the current canary. Need to sync with the inspector-folks

Comment: can you look at the screenshoot that I have, and I can't get my model's details show. It has only the path to the model.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug in inspector atm. Not sure if reported.

Comment: The only way to get info to show is if the file name isn't model.js, but modelName.js (see bottom of my answer)

Comment: That's nice awesome. I found a way to get around in MU mode. Thank you NullVoxPopuli